# How can I combine two generic-as-key for a type?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm trying to create a TS helper for React's `useState` hook. This is to be used for components' (functions) arguments/props as such:

```js
import { type Dispatch, type SetStateAction } from 'react';

export const ComponentOne = ({ clicked: boolean; setClicked: Dispatch<SetStateAction<boolean>> })
```

As you can see, it's quite cumbersome to have to write this every time, so, I built a builder type:

```js
export type Name<N extends string> = `set${Capitalize<N>}`;

export type Builder<N extends string, S> = {
  [key in N]: S;
} & {
  [key in Name<N>]: S;
};
```

If I go back to my code and tweak it a bit:

```js
export type Props = {
  className: string;
} & SetStateBuilder<'clicked', boolean>;

export const ComponentOne = ({ className, clicked, setClicked}: Props)...
```

it works, but the problem is that TS is showing them to me as such:

```js
type Props = {
    className: string;
} & {
    clicked: boolean;
} & {
    setClicked: boolean;
}
```

...not ideal! It'd be perfect if I could merge `clicked` and `setClicked` together. The keys coming from `Props` are fine as-is.

Unfortunately, if I try to just put `[key in N]: S;` and `[key in Name<N>]: S;` inside of `Builder`, TS sees them as equivalent, and removes one.

Would appreciate some help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the [Prettify](https://github.com/KamilHs/type-samurai/blob/main/src/prettify.d.ts?plain=1#L15) utility type from the [type-samurai](https://github.com/KamilHs/type-samurai) package. Simplified version:

```
type Prettify<T> = T extends infer R
  ? {
      [K in keyof R]: R[K];
    }
  : never;
```

This utility remaps the given type by using the [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html), which forces the compiler to remove *intersections*, type aliases, etc.

Testing:

```
type Prettify<T> = T extends infer R
  ? {
      [K in keyof R]: R[K];
    }
  : never;

export type Name<N extends string> = `set${Capitalize<N>}`;

export type Builder<N extends string, S> = Prettify<
  {
    [key in N]: S;
  } & {
    [key in Name<N>]: S;
  }
>;

// type Result = {
//   clicked: boolean;
//   setClicked: boolean;
// }
type Result = Builder<'clicked', boolean>;
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgBSgUxjYAzAnnAXzmyghDgHIZcw0BaAZwEMQBXKJ4CgbgFgAoAWgAekWHGq04AORZoAPNLgiYaAHYATBnAYwowNQHMAfHAC8cAAYMMAEgQBhJmGAwmAG2AAvBdOMFLPkF+ETF4STQ4ACFWYHcNNChFZWFVTW1dfSMAGjgAZVMLVAwsPHkBOEQKyrgAbQBrNHwDGQBdAC58oMqiADIq-hq6xua1GTlFYw6u6oIBYyCBAHoliRpIgCU0BlZ3eAsEZdXKgGNPE8aNToAjCAh3NCY1IJWamxgHc8ubu4enl9Wc34ETgWx2e3M0Vi8US8goZ2AFzQGgouVu90eagWAiAA)

Comment: Awesome! Was looking for a TS utilities library.